# Does Daniel 12:1–2 indicate the damned will have physical bodies like the Saints?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, resurrection, resurrection-body, daniel

In Daniel chapter 12 we are given some insight into the last days, and it appears the many who have been buried will awake. Does this mean that all will have the same type of resurrection body?

> [Daniel 12:1–2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+12%3A1%E2%80%932&version=NKJV)  (NKJV)
>   "At that time Michael shall stand up, The great prince who stands watch over the sons of your people; And there shall be a time of trouble, Such as never was since there was a nation, Even to that time. And at that time your people shall be delivered, Every one who is found written in the book. <sup>2</sup>  And many of those who sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, Some to everlasting life, Some to shame and everlasting contempt.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is the case, in some form or another.

This [article](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/1329-resurrection-of-the-wicked-the) gives a good discussion, including some of the other verses supporting this.

> Marvel not at this: for the hour comes, in which all that are in the
>   tombs shall hear his voice, and shall come forth; they that have done
>   good, unto the resurrection of life; **and they that have done evil,
>   unto the resurrection of judgment.**
>
> John 5:28-29, emphasis added

And,

> But this I confess unto you, that after the Way which they call a
>   sect, so serve I the God of our fathers, believing all things which
>   are according to the law, and which are written in the prophets;
>   having hope toward God, which these also themselves look for, **that
>   there shall be a resurrection both of the just and unjust**.
>
> Acts 24:14-15, emphasis added

I appreciate the article because it goes further into discussing the condition of the bodies they will have,

> The term clearly seems to indicate that the body of the wicked will
>   reflect a ruined condition, with the beauty of its earthly design
>   egregiously diminished, if not extinguished altogether. There is no
>   bodily “redemption” (Romans 8:23) for the rogue! One can only imagine
>   how horrible the scenes of hell could be.
>
> The resurrected bodies of the unrighteous will be susceptible to pain,
>   together with whatever “conscience” and “memory” torments they will
>   experience (cf. Luke 16:27-28).
>
> From the [article](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/1329-resurrection-of-the-wicked-the) cited above.

Other verses that would indicate this would be Revelation 20, the final resurrection, as well as Jesus' description of it in the end of Matthew 25 and 1 Corinthians 15.

Comment: Good question, well answered. +1 for both. Wish I could give +2. Even though I do not agree with a word.

Comment: @gideonmarx Feel free to answer it yourself.  There's bound to be differences of opinion. Just back up your answer.